# Can't install python library hopsworks. Running setup.py install did not run successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install the `hopsworks` library and I'm getting the error `Running setup.py install for twofish did not run successfully.` I tried installing the `wheel` package and tried in more than one virtual environment. Here is the full error message if it helps:

```
  Running setup.py install for twofish ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for twofish did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running install
      /home/kamr/miniconda3/envs/analysis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      copying twofish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_twofish' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/twofish-0.3
      gcc -pthread -B /home/kamr/miniconda3/envs/analysis/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/kamr/miniconda3/envs/analysis/include -I/home/kamr/miniconda3/envs/analysis/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/kamr/miniconda3/envs/analysis/include -fPIC -Itwofish-0.3 -I/home/kamr/miniconda3/envs/analysis/include/python3.9 -c twofish-0.3/twofish.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/twofish-0.3/twofish.o
      twofish-0.3/twofish.c:173:10: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
        173 | #include <string.h>     /* for memset(), memcpy(), and memcmp() */
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> twofish

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu `/usr/include/string.h` is in `libc6-dev`: `sudo apt install -y libc6-dev`